# Sed replace single text with content of file

Tags: bash, shell, sed, find

I have a question regarding using `sed`.

I have a JSON file and I want to get it inserted in another file.

What I'm trying is to get all the contents of the `.json` file which contains 4500 lines, and replace the specific text in my HTML:

```
{DATA_INPUT}
```

I have been using

```
DATA_JSON=$(echo "$(<data.json)")

sed -i "s/{DATA_INPUT}]{\}/${DATA_JSON}{\}/g" convert.html
```

But seems is not working,

And I'm getting

```
/bin/find: Argument list too long
```

I have also tried:

```
DATA_JSON=$(echo "$(<data.json)")
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'convert.html' \
    -exec sed -n "s/{DATA_INPUT}/${DATA_JSON}/g" {} \;
```

But getting:

```
 /bin/sed: Argument list too long
```

I'm trying to integrate this with Bash.

So basically I'm trying to get all the contents from the file and replace the text that I have in `convert.html`

Comment: Just `DATA_JSON="$(<data.json)"` btw. No reason to have an `echo` involved.

Comment: Does your JSON contain any characters that are meaningful to HTML? Do they need escaping?

Comment: Surely the `find` error message would come from your _second_ attempt? But anyway, the `find` attempt is just an overcomplication here.

Comment: Don't ask two things in one question. You only use `find` in your second example, so the first ne can not produce _/bin/find: Argument list too long_. Finally, _is not working_  is a poor problem description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed` already knows how to insert the contents of a file.

```
sed -i '/{DATA_INPUT}/r data.json' convert.html
```

In isolation, this will insert the contents of `data.json` on the following lines after the match. If you want to also manipulate the match, perhaps try something like

```
sed '/{DATA_INPUT}/!b;s///;r data.json' convert.html
```

(probably leave out the `-i` until you are satisfied that you have a working script) but this is still rather clunky and doesn't work correctly if you want to preserve the context around the `{DATA_INPUT}` token and keep it on either side of the inserted contents.

Perhaps it's more fruitful to try e.g. Awk or Perl, which are somewhat less read-only;

```
awk 'NR==FNR { gsub(/&/, "\\\\&"); lines = lines (lines ? "\n" : "") $0; next }
    /\{DATA_INPUT\}\{\}/ { sub(/\{DATA_INPUT\}/, lines) }
   1' data.json convert.html >new.html
```

Comment: In GNU sed perhaps `sed 's/{DATA_INPUT}//;T;r data.json' convert.html`?

Comment: @potong I generally try to avoid nonportable `sed` constructs (though even `b` in a string doesn't work out of the box on MacOS / BSD; you'd have to say `-e '/{DATA_INPUT}/!b' -e 's///;r data.json'`)

Comment: @tripleee that works perfectly, except : running `sed -i "s/{DATA_INPUT}/r data.json" convert.html`

Where I get : 
`sed: -e expression #1, char 26: unterminated `s' command` `

I just want to remove the part DATA_INPUT and replace the content from data.json

Comment: ` sed -i '/{DATA_INPUT}/!b;s///;r data.json' convert.html `

Works perfectly!

Comment: Perhaps `sed -e '/{DATA_INPUT}/{s///;r data.json' -e '}' convert.html`? Might need another `;` before the closing `}`.

Comment: Yeah, that works too. Whether or not you need semicolons or newlines around braces is another corner which isn't entirely well-defined, so I try to avoid that too.

Comment: FWIW some form of `\{DATA_INPUT\}\{\}/ { $0=lines }` (massage to work) would be more robust than doing a sub(). Maybe `BEGIN{tgt="{DATA_INPUT}"} ... s=index($0,tgt) { $0=substr($0,1,s-1) lines substr($0,s+length(tgt)) }` would be necessary, idk as there's no sample input/output in the question.